# If $a+b \varpropto a-b$, prove that $a^2+b^2 \varpropto ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b \varpropto a-b$, prove that $a^2+b^2 \varpropto ab$

$\Rightarrow a+b=k_1(a-b)$ and $a^2+b^2 = k_2ab \tag1$

$\Rightarrow (a+b)^2=k_1^2(a-b)^2 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2+2ab = k_1^2(a^2+b^2-2ab) \Rightarrow a^2+b^2 = k_1^2(a^2+b^2-2ab)-2ab$

Plug into $(1)$:

$\Rightarrow k_1^2(a^2b+b^2-2ab)-2ab=k_2ab \Rightarrow k_1^2(a^2+b^2-2ab)=ab(k_2+2)$

$\Rightarrow k_1^2a^2+k_1^2b^2-2abk_1^2=abk_2+2ab$

$\Rightarrow (a^2+b^2)k_1^2=ab(2k_1^2+k_2+2)$

$\Rightarrow a^2+b^2 = ab \dfrac{2k_1^2+k_2+2}{k_1^2}$

So $\dfrac{2k_1^2+k_2+2}{k_1^2}=k_2$,and they are both constants of variation, thus it is proven that $a^2+b^2 \varpropto ab$?

Comment: Please define $\varpropto$ *explicitely*, and *before* using it.

Comment: I think it's the simplest most straightforward case. But I don't really understand what defining the variation explicitly means.

Comment: I mean define the meaning of this symbol in your context.

Comment: If $a+b$ varies with $a-b$, prove that $a^2+b^2$ varies with $ab$

Comment: What does "varies with" mean? Where do $a,b$ live?

Comment: I mean vary this way: if a train is moving at a uniform rate of 40 miles in 60 minutes, it will travel 20 miles in 30 minutes, 80 miles in 120 minutes, and so on. I don't know where $a,b$ live or what this means.

Comment: Oh, fine! $c,d$ being functions with numerical  (real?) values, $c\varpropto d$ means either there exists a (real?) constant $k$ such that $c=kd$, or $d=0$. Maybe you should insert something like this at the beginning of your post.

Comment: This is a Mathematics forum. In Mathematics things are defined in a precise manner in terms of numbers, functions, sets, other mathematical objects, etc. Referring to physical quantities like time or velocity is not considered a Mathematical definition.

Comment: So, I guess $\varpropto$ means "is proportional to"? Can you please confirm?

Comment: And can you confirm my "or $d=0$"? Otherwise, your theorem is false because $a+0=a-0$ but $a^2+0^2 \not\varpropto a0.$

Comment: When you have $a^2+b^2 = k_1^2(a^2+b^2-2ab)-2ab$, don't "plug into (1)", just regroup all the $(a^2+b^2)$ on the left of the equal sign and all the rest on the right of the equal sign.

Comment: Thanks Stef I took your suggestion and edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$
4ab = (a+b)^2-(a-b)^2 = (k_1^2-1)(a-b)^2=(k_1^2-1)(a^2+b^2)+[2(1-k_1^2)]ab.
$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: How did you go from $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$ to  $(k_1^2-1)(a-b)^2$?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Did you tried to get that by yourself? we can't make all the work for you.